# Retrieving a single colum from a pivot table - Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I am using a pivot table *genre_user* to relate *user* to *genre*. 
table contains the following fields

```
id 
user_id 
genre_id
```

Following are the model definitions

User.php

```
public function genres() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Genre');
    }
```

Genre.php

```
public function artists() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
```

I am getting the results as a collection when I use the following code

```
$user = auth()->user();
dd($user->genres);
```

I want to show the selected genres in a dropdown field of genres. Is it possible to get only the current users *genre_id* as an array from the pivot table without using a *foreach* loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what will help you achieve this behavior is the `lists()` method.
Try something like

`$user_genres = auth()->user()->genres()->lists('name','id');`

If you are using Forms & HTML package you can just do

`{!! Form::select('genres',$user_genres,null) !!}`

And here is your dropdown

More info [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#selects) (scroll down to "Retrieving A List Of Column Values")

Comment: What did you try? Did you undestand how lists method works?
Eloquent is just a wrapper for your database. When you 
do `$user()->genres()->get()` you are just returning a collection of the related instances. Using the lists method you can get just a specific column as an array with a second parameter used as the key of the array. Also take a look @pespantelis answer. Have you created the correct relationships inside your model?

Comment: Sorry , It did work. It was a mistake in the code. I figured it out. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

A `user` should have one `genre`.

Therefore, your models should contain the following relations:

*User.php*

```
public function genre() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Genre');
}
```

*Genre.php*

```
public function artists() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}
```

Comment: pespantelis, the user can have multiple genre.

Comment: I would like to know what you think. :P